# Eclipse help, import not recognized

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I am trying to use the import of org.apache. However when I put it into my eclipse project it gives me redline errors and it says it does not recognize the import.

What should I do?
Thanks

By the way I am basically trying to import this code into eclipse:

[How to log onto a HTTPS website with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695069/how-to-log-onto-a-https-website-with-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right click on your project, choose `Build Path` -> `Add External Archives...` and then choose the `jar` file that contains the apache classes

Comment: Thanks. Also this link for anyone who needs the jar file http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Answer (score 0):

It is usually part of HttpComponents Client 4.x jar file.